# Dimension reduction by identifying important Variables

Tags: python, pca, variance, dimensionality-reduction

I have a np.array with 400 entries, each containing the values of a spectrum with 1000 points. 
I want to identify the n most interesting indices of the spectrum and return them. So I can visualize and use them as an input vector for my classificator.

Is it best to calculate the variance, apply a PCA or are there better-suited algorithms?
And how do I compute the accounted variance for that selection?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dimensionality reduction can be performed in two different broad ways: [feature extraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_extraction) and [feature selection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_selection). PCA is more suited for feature extraction, while "identify the n most interesting indices" is a feature selection problem. More details and how to code it up here: [sklearn.feature_selection](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_selection.html)